# Files cannot be found despite existing

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have this bot and it had no issues when I first had this code and was working on adding some functions and commands, but today it just cannot find any file in the commands folder for some reason.

Right now it says it cannot find `.DS_Store`, and when I change it to a folder with my javascript commands, it says it can't even find those files either, despite them absolutely being there. I tried redoing it all but I have no clue what's wrong with these few lines.

This is the code that gets all the files needed

```js
const functions = fs.readdirSync("./src/functions").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src/events").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync("./src/commands");

(async () => {
    for (file of functions) {
        require(`./functions/${file}`)(client);
    }
    client.handleEvents(eventFiles, "./src/events");
    client.handleCommands(commandFolders, "./src/commands");
    client.login(process.env.token)
})();
```

And this is where the error is thrown by saying:

> Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir `./src/commands/.DS_Store`

```js
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`${path}/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
```

Comment: It seems `.DS_Store` is not a directory, and you are trying to read it as one.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing as the two above where I read the javascript files, but then for some reason the commands don't show up, but the bot does come online with no errors, should I just only try to read non directories then, cause just the javascript files aren't enough